# Copy selected row to a new row in destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move a selected row of data to a new row in a destination sheet.

I have the code below. It overwrites the row above the last row in the destination sheet.

I would like it to insert a new row in the destination sheet.

```
Sub move_row()

'Declare variables
 Dim sht1 As Worksheet
 Dim sht2 As Worksheet
 Dim sht3 As Worksheet
 Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("Incremental Opps")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Forecast Data")

'Select Entire Row
Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Selection
    .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow - 1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this without new line

```
Sub move_row()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

with new line (Insert)

```
Sub move_row()
    Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Worksheets("Forecast Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized this still overwrites the row above the total row in the 'Forecast Data' sheet. Is there a way to use the above code, but insert a new row?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line to the following:

```
.Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that adds it below the last row which is the totals for columns in a table, i would like the copied row to sit above this so it is included in the table and the values are totaled in the last row.